# Eshell: run function when changing directory

Tags: eshell

I'd like to run a function whenever the current directory in `eshell` changes (like a `eshell-chdir-hook`, but that doesn't exist). How can I do this?

Comment: There are functions within `eshell` that detect things like a `cd ...` entry, which triggers an elisp function -- e.g., `eshell/cd` -- depending upon whether certain modules have been loaded.  You could modify that function and  attach your own hook, depending upon whether you use that particular module.  I took over `eshell` completely by making one large custom library and I no longer use modules, but it shouldn't be difficult to track down if you need some further assistance.

Comment: No idea whether there is an Emacs hook for this, but you could presumably use a (shell) alias to change directories, and have that alias invoke Emacs in batch mode to invoke some Emacs function. Not saying this is a great solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well duh. The answer is to use `eshell-directory-change-hook`.

Comment: Yep, there it is at the bottom of `eshell/cd`

Comment: @lawlist yup. :) Thanks for the tip.